# react framer motion. stuff is not animating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have a log in component with some motion-framer animations. here is the componenet:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Hoshen from "../../assets/hoshen logo.png";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import styled from "styled-components/macro";
import { pageAnimation, fade, photoAnim } from "../../animation";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import axios from "axios";

function LogIn({ setUser }) {

 return (
   <LogInStyled>
     <LogInWrap
       exit="exit"
       variants={pageAnimation}
       initial="hidden"
       animate="show"
     >
       <div className="Logo">
         <motion.img
           whileHover={{
             rotate: 360,
             transition: { duration: 0.8 },
           }}
           variants={photoAnim}
           src={Hoshen}
           alt="logo"
         />
       </div>
       <FormStyled>
         <Input
           variants={fade}
           whileTap={{ scale: 1.1 }}
           type="text"
           placeholder="מספר אישי"
          
         />
         <Input
           variants={fade}
           whileTap={{ scale: 1.1 }}
           type="password"
           placeholder="סיסמא"
           
         />

         <Button
           variants={fade}
           whileTap={{ scale: 10 }}
         >
           log In
         </Button>
       </FormStyled>
     </LogInWrap>
   </LogInStyled>
 );
}

const LogInStyled = styled(motion.div)`
//some styles
`;

const LogInWrap = styled(motion.div)`
 //some styles
`;

const FormStyled = styled.div`
 //some styles
`;

const Input = styled(motion.input)`
 //some styles
`;

const Button = styled(motion.button)`
 //some styles
`;

export default LogIn;
```

the animations:

```
export const pageAnimation = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    y: 300,
  },
  show: {
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0,
    transition: {
      duration: 0.5,
      when: "beforeChildren",
      staggerChildren: 0.1,
    },
  },
  exit: {
    opacity: 0,
    y: -300,
    transition: {
      duration: 0.5,
    },
  },
};

export const fade = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0 },
  show: {
    opacity: 1,
    transition: { ease: "easeOut", duration: 0.3 },
  },
};

export const photoAnim = {
  hidden: { scale: 1.5, opacity: 0 },
  show: {
    scale: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      ease: "easeOut",
      duration: 0.3,
    },
  },
};
```

the problem - When the project compiles first time everything works as it should:

[image: everything works]

but after you refresh that page, the animations are not working. every thing stays on opacity:0. I can see the html elements on chrome dev tools. but cannot find a way to understand why this is happening! the absurd part to me is that the same code works fine in another project. the same. appreciate your help.

the strange behavior :
[image]

dev tools(you can see the opacity is 0):

[image]

Comment: Any console errors? If you want to animate the mount/unmount of components you need to use ```AnimatePresence```, otherwise the exit prop wont work

Comment: Here are the docs: https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/

Comment: no console errors. and I am using AnimatePresence in the App.js. feeling stuck cant find a clue why this is happening ):

Comment: I found that this piece of code is problematic: transition: {
      duration: 0.5,
      when: "beforeChildren",
      staggerChildren: 0.1,
    },

Comment: cant find out why it works in another project just fine